# Port timeout deploying Loopback app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, loopbackjs

I deployed an Loopback app to Heroku, but it keeps crashing with error

`Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

I know it could be connected to the dynamic port of Heroku, so I set my port to the process environment one doing

```
app.start = function () {
  // start the web server

  var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  app.set('port', port);

  app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
  app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../.tmp')));

  return app.listen(function () {
    app.emit('started');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', app.get('url'));
  });
};
```

but this didn't fix the issue.
Any idea?

Comment: You didn't bind any port. Try `app.listen(app.get('port'), ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can force Heroku to use provided port by modifying the code as provided in the [documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#app-listen). If you can't relate to api docs, don't worry it's because javascript is flexible.

```
app.start = function () {
  // start the web server

  var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
  app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../.tmp')));

  return app.listen(port, function () {
    app.emit('started');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', app.get('url'));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had thesame problem. I solved it by adding an environment variable `HOST=0.0.0.0` in my Heroku app.

[image: Heroku app environment variables]